# Add Depandent drop down list for Django admin user

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have created 4 models in my django Country, State, and City, and also add them in admin.site.register How Can I add dependent drop down list for Country State City for admin user whenever user try to create Aplications object, they get state name list depends on Country name selected by admin user, and also for city.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import ForeignKey
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField


class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    phone_code = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.ForeignKey(to=Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class City(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(to=State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Applications(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()
    email_id = models.EmailField()
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    current_company = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: Are you familiar with javascript? IMHO you need to add dynamic behaviour to your admin form.

Answer (score 0):

> they get state name list depends on Country name selected by admin user, and also for city

Since you said a dropdown list, I will suggest switching over to a [multiple choice field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) where the choices will be set to a certain range of values and will appear as a dropdown in the admin dashboard.